# How to instantiate a model entity from queryRunner.manager.query() results

Tags: typeorm

We have a use-case that requires us to use `queryRunner.manager.query();` and not Repositories.

The table which we are querying has columns that are mapped to properties on our entity class, where some of the table column names differ from the property names used in our entity class.

For example,

```js
@Entity('Car')
export class Car {
   @Column('character varying', { name: 'make' }
   type: string;
}
```

In this case, the entity `"Car"` has a column named `"make"` in the DB that is ***mapped*** to a property named `"type"`, in the entity class.

**Question**: is there a way to instantiate an entity type from our model using the results from `queryRunner.query()`?

For example, something like:

```js
const results = await dbConnection.queryRunner.manager.query(
  `select * from cars where id = $1`,
  [1]
);

// this is not valid TypeORM, but it conveys the idea
const car = new Car(results[0]);
```

Comment: This statement is quite confusing. --_The table which we are querying has columns that are mapped to properties on our entity class, where some of the table column names differ from the property names used in our entity class._--

Comment: Agree @fortunee, thanks for pointing that out.  Is this clearer now?

Comment: What happens if you tried `const car = new Car(); \n car[results[0]]`

Comment: First does result return the column name?